# Add CheckBox to Datagridview Header in C# and change place of checkbox with change scrolbar

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I use this code to locate a checkbox in Header of Datagridview. But with changing scrolbar of datagridview, locate of checkbox changed.

```
        // customize dataviewgrid, add checkbox column
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkboxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        checkboxColumn.Width = 30;
        checkboxColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxColumn);

        // add checkbox header
        Rectangle rect = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);

        // set checkbox header to center of header cell. +1 pixel to position correctly.
        rect.X = rect.Location.X + 8;
        rect.Y = rect.Location.Y + 10;
        rect.Width  = rect.Size.Width;
        rect.Height  = rect.Size.Height;

        CheckBox checkboxHeader = new CheckBox();
        checkboxHeader.Name = "checkboxHeader";
        checkboxHeader.Size = new Size(15, 15);
        checkboxHeader.Location = rect.Location;
        checkboxHeader.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged);

        dataGridView1.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader);
```

Like this pictures :

[image]

Comment: You mention, *"I use this code,"* but I don't see any code in your post.

Comment: sorry i am inserting the code.

Comment: don't understand you question, you added a check box in the header of column.  What is it about the scroll bar that you need help on?

Comment: when scroll bar moved, the location of checkbox in header too changed. I want to fix location of checkbox in header.

Comment: Don't add checkbox, draw one.

Answer (score 0):

It was very easy. I use this code and solved it.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
```